# Scaling predictors in lmer (lme4) changes intercept to insignificant

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, scale-parameter

I ran a multilevel model (`lmer`; package `lme4`) which provides me with unstandardized coefficients. I tried getting the standardized coefficients in multiple ways (by using the `scale()` function to scale the entire dataset, using the `scale()` function for predictors in the lmer function (see example below), and through the `effectsize` package. The output of three methods is quite similar.

However, in the original model (unscaled), the intercept is significant. When I run the same model with scaled predictors, or when I ask for the standardized coefficients through the effectsize package, the intercept becomes insignificant. Is this because the data is now scaled? Or am I missing a crucial step?

Here is an example of the original model output:

```
> summary(model)
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: y ~ 1 + x + (1 | id)
   Data: data

REML criterion at convergence: 11788.7

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.1878 -0.4737  0.0658  0.6285  3.5090 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 0.6767   0.8226  
 Residual             1.0441   1.0218  
Number of obs: 3972, groups:  id, 105

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error         df t value            Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    5.14309    0.08191  103.85216  62.787 <0.0000000000000002 ***
x              0.05039    0.04087 3865.85554   1.233               0.218    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
     (Intr)
x    0.000
```

Here's an example of the output when variables x and y are scaled:

```
> summary(model_scaled)
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: scale(y) ~ 1 + scale(x) + (1 | id)
   Data: data

REML criterion at convergence: 9690.3

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.1878 -0.4737  0.0658  0.6285  3.5090 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 0.3987   0.6314  
 Residual             0.6151   0.7843  
Number of obs: 3972, groups:  id, 105

Fixed effects:
               Estimate  Std. Error          df t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   -0.009642    0.062875  103.852160  -0.153    0.878
scale(x)       0.015345    0.012446 3865.855541   1.233    0.218

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
scale(x)    0.000
```

Here's an example of the output from the `effectsize` package:

```
> standardize_parameters(model, method = "refit")
# Standardization method: refit
Parameter   | Std. Coef. |        95% CI
----------------------------------------
(Intercept) |  -0.00572  | [-0.13, 0.12]
x           |       0.02 | [-0.01, 0.04]
```

Note that the Intercept is significant in the first model, but not in the second model, nor in the estimates derived from the effectsize package. Does someone have an answer?

Comment: Why do you scale the response as in `scale(y) ~ 1 + scale(x) + (1 | id)`. I don't see how this would give meaningful results.